# Combine file names and content

Tags: linux, awk

I got several files like this:

First file is named `XXX`

```
1
2
3
```

Second file is named `YYY`

```
4
5
6
```

I would like to write content and the file names to a separate file that would look like this:

```
1 XXX
2 XXX
3 XXX
4 YYY
5 YYY
6 YYY
```

Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{print $0,FILENAME}' file1 file2
```

Or Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts "#{$_.chomp} #{ARGF.filename}"' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Without further explanation of what you actually need this should work:

```
for file in $(ls)
do
  echo -n $file >> outfile
  cat $file >> outfile
done
```

Comment: use shell expansion: `for file in *`